# Join two table columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables as shown below:

#### teams

```
teamid   team_name

  1      Rockstars
  2      Gangsters
```

#### team_members

```
teamid    team_member_name
  1         Rob
  1         Mike
  2         John
  2         Paul
```

I want to get the result like this:

```
teamid      team_members    team_name

   1        Rob, Mike       Rockstars
   2        John, Paul      Gangsters
```

I tried this: (*isn't working*)

```
Select teamid, CONCAT(select team_member_name FROM team_members WHERE teams.teamid = team_members.teamid) as team_members FROM teams;
```

Please help

Comment: Can you give SQL Fiddle so you can get quick answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is [**`GROUP_CONCAT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT t1.teamid, t1.team_name, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.team_member_name)
FROM teams AS t1
INNER JOIN team_members AS t2 ON t1.teamid = t2.teamid
GROUP BY t1.teamid, t1.team_name
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df987a/1)

Comment: `GROUP BY teamid, team_name` will give conflict error

Comment: @GordonLinoff You are late `GiorgosBetsos` changed his answer.